# Структурировать пост из существующих массивов с объектами

Tags: javascript, html, json

необходимо из трех имеющихся массивов с объектами собрать посты, в которых будет указываться непосредственно текст поста, информация об авторе и комментарии к этому посту.

База данных имеет следующий вид:

Переменная с текстом поста и его айди

```
var posts = [
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio",
"body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "qui est esse",
"body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint "
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 3,
"title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
"body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem"
}]
```

Переменная с информацией об авторе:

```
const users = [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kulas Light",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
 }
}]
```

И массив с комментариями к посту:

```
var comments = [
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 1,
"name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
"email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
"body": "laudantium enim quasi est "
},
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 2,
"name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
"email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
"body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis 
 occaecati quod ulla"
},
{
"postId": 1,
"id": 3,
"name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
"email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
"body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita 
 occaecati aliquam"
 }]
```

Необходимо всю эту информацию связать в один блок и вывести на экран, внешний вид не важен, так как хочу понять саму логику работы. Спасибо за любую информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(let p in posts){
    var post = posts[p];
    post.comments = [];
    post.users = [];

    for (let c in comments){
        var comment = comments[c];

        if(comment.postId == post.id){
            post.comments.push(comment);
        }
    }

    for (let u in users){
        var user = users[u];

        if(user.id == post.userId){
            post.users.push(user);
        }
    }
}

console.log(posts);
```